# Rails MVC with a GUI library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface, jruby

I wonder if it is possible to use Rails as a MVC model with GUI libraries (for example wxruby, gtkruby, java w/jruby) for ruby instead of a web server fronted and instead of rendering as html, js, xml or json etc?

Has anyone done this or have examples of such an implementation?

Is there such a gem for rails that adds these features and replaces tiny, mongrel etc as a wrapper?

Comment: I don't think this quite answers your question, but Rhodes is a Rails-like framework for creating native mobile apps on iPhone, Android, etc. http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/

Answer (score 1):

It is sort of possible to use Rails3 the way you want. This is because the re-architecting of Rails done for version 3 made most of the guts of rails modular.  So you can pick and choose the parts you want to use for whatever you want to do.  So you can use the backend modules Active[whatever] and use them with whatever other libraries you want.